# contact id reciver burgar alarm signals and push them to my webapp

Tags: security, humhub

I have built a webapp for an security company.  They monitor burglar alarms using contact-id.

I would like to send the signals appearing on the central monitoring server (using listener light), to a panel in my humhub webapp.  The information online is minimal.  What could help, is that listener uses a sql database.  Something that might work as a hack, would be to send the monitoring pc's screen to a iframe in the app.

Is there a way to have a screen broadcast privately to a iframe, or even a web based remote access of said screen?